# Execution freezes when I try to allocate Array in Armv8 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, armv8

So I am programming in assemply, this is just a simple code so I can learn how to allocate arrays in order to use them on NEON programming later.

```
ASM_FUNC(FPE)
.data
.balign 8

array: .skip 80 
array1: .word 10,20,30,40

.text

ldr x0,=array
mov x1,#10

check: 
      cmp x1,#1
      bne loop
      b exit

loop:
      str x1,[x0],#8 //Stores the value in x1 into x0 and moves the address +8 bytes
      sub x1,x1,#1   //x1--
      b check


exit:
      mov x0,#11
          ret
```

So, some parts are commented so I could try to find where the code is breaking (I don't have debug on my system).
I started commenting the calculation part and added a mov x0,#11 in the end right before the ret to see if the problem was on the calculation. Turns out it was not.
When I uncommented the array: .skip 80  and ldr x0,=array my application would just stick there if no response.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am using A64 on armv8 assembly

The entry point is called from this c program:

```
void  PocAsm_EntryPoint ( )
    {
    
    
          Print(L"========== ASM ==========\n");
       
        
          UINT32 fff = FPE();
          Print(L" %d \n",fff);
        
          Print(L"=========== ASM ===========\n");
        
          Print(L"Test version 0.24 \n");
      return 0;
    }
```

Unfortunately I didn't find the definition of the Print, so I apologize

Comment: You're on a 64-bit machine and a 64-bit value is 8 bytes, not 4.  If you want to store a 32-bit value you should store `w1` instead of `x1`.

Comment: Also, your code needs an entry point.  How are you assembling and linking this?  And as written all the executable code is in the `.data` section; it should be in `.text`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the code and edited it in the question, but I still achieve the same results: The application freezes.
I am using a pre-OS UEFI based in c. I will also edit the entrypoint

Comment: Could you provide more details on your algorithm in your question ? what exactly is it supposed to do ?. Do you want to 'allocate' the array (IMHO this is already done by the .word and .skip directives), or do you mean 'initialize'? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your linker and loader work, but what happens if you move `ASM_FUNC(FPE)` to be immediately after the `.text`?  I wonder if it is putting the label at the location of the array, so that you execute the data in the array instead of your intended code.

Comment: @Frant, so the whole point o f the algorithm is to create an array and post some numbers in it, there is no big deal th it.

Comment: @NateEldredge, this 'ASM_FUNC(FPE) '  is what the C program uses to call the assembly function. It is basically the name of the function.

Comment: Yes, right.  I'm asking about where it's located in the file.  It's presumably a macro, but what does it expand to?  And how does the system know where in your assembly code execution should begin?  If it's "the start of the text section" then it should be okay, but if it's "the start of the file" or "wherever the `ASM_FUNC` macro is located" then it will execute data.

Comment: @NateEldredge, not really a Macro. As you can see on the code, I can call an assembly function directly from the C program just by calling     FPE()    function.
The assembly code should begin just in the line after ASM_FUNC(FPE). But the actual start of the code should begin on .text

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to answer to the following question: does the `FPE()` function work as expected, while removing everything else from the equation, using standard tools such as `qemu-system-aarch64` and `GDB`.

The code for the `FPE()` function will be compiled for a Cortex-A53 qemu-virt machine.

*Prerequisites:*

- qemu-system-aarch64 is installed:

**Ubuntu 20.04**: `sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm`
**Windows 10**: download and install the `qemu-w64-setup-20201120.exe` installer from [here](http://qemu-w64-setup-20201120.exe).

- the `aarch64-none-elf` toolchain for `Cortex-A` is installed. It can be downloaded from the [ARM WEB site](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads). There are versions for both Linux and Windows 10.

`FPE.s`:

```
        .arch armv8-a
        .file   "FPE.s"

        .data
        .balign 8
        .globl array
array:  .skip 80 
array1: .word 10,20,30,40

        .text
        .align  2
        .globl FPE
FPE:
        ldr x0,=array
        mov x1,#10

check: 
        cmp x1,#1
        bne loop
        b exit

loop:
        str x1,[x0],#8  //Stores the value in x1 into x0 and moves the address +8 bits
        sub x1,x1,#1    //x1--
        b check

exit:
        mov x0,#11
        ret
        .end
```

`startup.s`:

```
                .title startup64.s
                .arch armv8-a
                .text
                .section .text.startup,"ax"    
                .globl _start
_start:
                ldr x0, =__StackTop
                mov sp, x0
                bl FPE
wait:           wfe
                b wait
               .end
```

*Building:*

We will build `FPE.elf` for the qemu-virt machine (RAM starts at `0x40000000`):

```
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -g -Wl,--defsym,__StackTop=0x40010000 -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x40000000 -o FPE.elf startup.s FPE.s
```

*Debugging:*

Start qemu in a shell:

```
/opt/qemu-5.1.0/bin/qemu-system-aarch64  -semihosting -m 1M -nographic -serial telnet::4444,server,nowait -machine virt,gic-version=2,secure=on,virtualization=on -S -gdb tcp::1234,ipv4 -cpu cortex-a53 -kernel FPE.elf
```

Start `GDB`:

```
opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gdb  --quiet -nx -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' -ex 'load' --ex 'b _start' -ex 'b exit' FPE.elf
```

`GDB` should start:

```
Reading symbols from FPE.elf...
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
_start () at startup.s:7
7                       ldr x0, =__StackTop
Loading section .text, size 0x50 lma 0x40000000
Loading section .data, size 0x60 lma 0x40010050
Start address 0x40000000, load size 176
Transfer rate: 85 KB/sec, 88 bytes/write.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40000000: file startup.s, line 7.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40000040: file FPE.s, line 28.
```

From this point, the commands `stepi`, `p/x $x0`, and `x/10g 0x40010050` could be used for monitoring the program behavior until it will reach the `exit` label.

We will just here display the 10 elements in the array at the start and exit breakpoints:

```
gdb) x/10g 0x40010050
0x40010050:     0       0
0x40010060:     0       0
0x40010070:     0       0
0x40010080:     0       0
0x40010090:     0       0
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, exit () at FPE.s:28
28              mov x0,#11
(gdb) x/10g 0x40010050
0x40010050:     10      9
0x40010060:     8       7
0x40010070:     6       5
0x40010080:     4       3
0x40010090:     2       0
```

Single-stepping from this point shows that the program returns properly from its execution:

```
(gdb) stepi
29              ret
(gdb) stepi
wait () at startup.s:10
10      wait:           wfe
(gdb) stepi
11                      b wait
(gdb) stepi
10      wait:           wfe
```

The answer to the question would therefore be: Yes, the code for the `FPE()` function is working properly.

The exact same procedure can be run on Windows 10, this is just a matter of adjusting the three commands that were used for running `aarch64-none-elf-gcc`, `qemu-system-aarch64` and `GDB`.

---

Comparing a dump of your object file with the one I tested may help understanding the issue:

```
/opt.arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-as -o FPE.o FPE.s
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-objdump -D FPE.o 

FPE.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <FPE>:
   0:   58000140        ldr     x0, 28 <exit+0x8>
   4:   d2800141        mov     x1, #0xa                        // #10

0000000000000008 <check>:
   8:   f100043f        cmp     x1, #0x1
   c:   54000041        b.ne    14 <loop>  // b.any
  10:   14000004        b       20 <exit>

0000000000000014 <loop>:
  14:   f8008401        str     x1, [x0], #8
  18:   d1000421        sub     x1, x1, #0x1
  1c:   17fffffb        b       8 <check>

0000000000000020 <exit>:
  20:   d2800160        mov     x0, #0xb                        // #11
  24:   d65f03c0        ret
        ...

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <array>:
        ...

0000000000000050 <array1>:
  50:   0000000a        .inst   0x0000000a ; undefined
  54:   00000014        .inst   0x00000014 ; undefined
  58:   0000001e        .inst   0x0000001e ; undefined
  5c:   00000028        .inst   0x00000028 ; undefined
```

Dumping the complete ELF file of the minimal example would give:

```
opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-objdump -D FPE.elf

FPE.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000040000000 <_start>:
    40000000:   580000c0        ldr     x0, 40000018 <wait+0xc>
    40000004:   9100001f        mov     sp, x0
    40000008:   94000006        bl      40000020 <FPE>

000000004000000c <wait>:
    4000000c:   d503205f        wfe
    40000010:   17ffffff        b       4000000c <wait>
    40000014:   00000000        .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined
    40000018:   40010000        .inst   0x40010000 ; undefined
    4000001c:   00000000        .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined

0000000040000020 <FPE>:
    40000020:   58000140        ldr     x0, 40000048 <exit+0x8>
    40000024:   d2800141        mov     x1, #0xa                        // #10

0000000040000028 <check>:
    40000028:   f100043f        cmp     x1, #0x1
    4000002c:   54000041        b.ne    40000034 <loop>  // b.any
    40000030:   14000004        b       40000040 <exit>

0000000040000034 <loop>:
    40000034:   f8008401        str     x1, [x0], #8
    40000038:   d1000421        sub     x1, x1, #0x1
    4000003c:   17fffffb        b       40000028 <check>

0000000040000040 <exit>:
    40000040:   d2800160        mov     x0, #0xb                        // #11
    40000044:   d65f03c0        ret
    40000048:   40010050        .inst   0x40010050 ; undefined
    4000004c:   00000000        .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000040010050 <__data_start>:
        ...

00000000400100a0 <array1>:
    400100a0:   0000000a        .inst   0x0000000a ; undefined
    400100a4:   00000014        .inst   0x00000014 ; undefined
    400100a8:   0000001e        .inst   0x0000001e ; undefined
    400100ac:   00000028        .inst   0x00000028 ; undefined
```

Comment: Ok. So I made some testes to see in which line the code was getting stuck. 
I commented the whole code and left only
`array: .skip 80 

mov x0,#10`

and it got stuck
Than I tried:

`array1: .word 10,20,30,40

mov x0,#10`

Again, stuck.
What us the problem with those lines?

Comment: By some tests, do you mean using GDB and QEMU ? By the way, you did not tell which  compiler/assembler softwares you are using. Can you provide a disassembly of FPE.o ? (assuming your assembly code is in FPE.s) ? could you create a minimal example similar to mine ? this would allow you to debug your code with qemu and GDB, and this would be IMHO the best way to find the what is not working.

Comment: I augmented my answer with an `objdump` output of the `FPE.o` object file, this would be very useful if you were augmenting your answer with the dump of your own object file: they should be very similar.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort and help. After some tests, I realized the mistake is just by allocating the vector. What could I be doing wrong?
Could you provide me with a very simple minimal working code which allocates an array of 10 numbers into the x0 register? This is the big problem I am facing in my code.
Thank you very much

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions, nor did you comment on whether or not the code I have assembled/debugged was the one you were trying to make work. In those conditions, I think I cannot help further.