# How do I allocate a vector in armv8 assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, armv8

So, I am trying to allocate a vector in armv8, here is the code

```
ASM_FUNC(test)
.data
array: .word 10,20,30,40

.text
mov    x0,#5
ret
```

It compiles, but when i try to run, it just gets stuck.
How can I properly declare and allocate a vector in assembly armv8?
Do I have to put a `.data.` before? And then put a `.code` on the operations?

This is the c code I am using

```
int test();

int main(void)
{
 int ff = test();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can allocate read-only data in `.text` but you need to make sure it's not in the execution path.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  The code as you posted it does not look wrong, so the error is likely in the code you did not show us.  Always provide all code needed to reproduce your issue.  Make sure to cut out all parts that are irrelevant but leave a program than can be assembled and ran without adding any extra parts.

Comment: @fuz, I understand what your point is. the problem is: There is no other part of the code at all. I just want to know what I need to do before allocating a vector.
However, I added the very basic "rest of the code" to the question

Comment: @MilosNovak Well, the directive is correct, but the way you have done it right now, the array is in the path of execution, so when `test` is called, the CPU is going to try and execute your array as code.  You should but the array–like all variables–into the `.rodata` (for read only variables) or `.data` (for writable variables) section.

Comment: @fuz, I tried again and updated the used code on the question.
It still freezes

Comment: @MilosNovak `ASM_FUNC(test)` is where your function begins.  It needs to be right before the first instruction of your function.  Your code places this who knows where, causing execution of the function to go astray.  As I said earlier, the variable must be outside of the execution path of the  function.  There is no such thing as having a variable inside a function in assembly.

Comment: @Milos Novak: your question is remarkably similar to the one asked by Marlon Pedersoli [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991510/execution-freezes-when-i-try-to-allocate-array-in-armv8-assembly). I would suggest you to provide at least a complete disassembly of the object file containing your test function, as well as the exact compiler/assembler versions you are using, or to debug your code compiled for qemu-virt machine using QEMU. And you did not provide a minimal reproducible example yet...

Comment: @Milos Novak: the linker script you are using is an important piece of the "rest of the code", and you did not provide it. And a pointer to the documentation for the non-standard `ASM_FUNC()` statement you are using is missing too. You may consider this does not matter, but it really does...