# REV16 ARMV8 assembly Instruction

Tags: assembly, neon, armv8

So, guys. I am making a simple code just to test the REV16 instruction on armv8 assembly.
This is my code

```
      .data //Indicates that this section initiates the variables
            oneHundredSeven: .word 170
            
.bss
            empty_variable: .space 64
            
.text //Indicates the code section starts here
    
              ASM_FUNC(REV16) //this is the entrypoint
            ldr    x1,=oneHundredSeven  //Loads the memory address of "oneHundredSeven" variable into the x1 register
      ldr    x2,=empty_variable   //Loads the memory address of "empty_variable"  variable into the x2 register
      mov    x3,#43520            //Moves the expected result to x3
    
      LD1   {V0.16B},[x1]         //Loads the value from the memory address saved on x1 to the V0 neon register
      REV16  V1.16B, V0.16B       //Reverts the bits on the V0 neon register and saves on the V1 neon register 
                                  //This instruction splits the 128-bit V1 register into eight 16-bit containers
                                  //divided into two sub containers of 8-bits
                    
      MOV    x2,V1.D[0]           //Set x2 to the value of the first double word in V0
    
      cmp    x2,x3                //Compares the value of x2 and x3
      b.ne   Neon_rev16_error     //if different, go to test_erro
      b      Neon_rev16_end       //if equal, go to test_end
    
    Neon_rev16_error:
      mov    x0,x2                //Loads the value on x2 to the return register (x0)
      ret
    
    Neon_rev16_end:
      mov    x0,#0                //Loads the value #6 to the regurn register (x0)
      ret
```

This is the C code that calls it

```
int main(void)
{
  long int fff = REV16(); //it calls the function in assembly, starts the entry point
  print(f"REV16 %lu \n",fff);

 return 0;
}
```

So, firstly I used `mov x4,x2`, but it was going to `Neon_rev16_error:`label and returning the expected result (43520) and that was a problem. If it is returning the expected result, why is it going to  `Neon_rev16_error:`? Than I realized it was probably moving the memory address sabed on x4, not the value on that. For that reason I changed to `ldr    x4,[x2]` but in this case, my application just freezes.

Do you guys have any idea of what I can do to make my code properly work?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What's the point of `empty_variable` supposed to be?  You load its address into `x2`, but never do anything with it, and then `mov x2, v1.d[0]` overwrites it.  Now `x2` contains the result from the `REV16` which is certainly not an address, but you then try to use it as an address anyway with the subsequent `ldr`?

Comment: @NateEldredge, the `empty_variable` allocates memory and  then I load this memory address to the x2 register.

As stated previously, first I tried to  use x2 in the `cmp    x2,x3`  instruction, just like that: ` cmp    x2,x3 ` , however, the code kept returning the expected result expected result (43520) saved on x3. That is wy I thought it was trying to compare x3 with the memory address on x2. 

If x2 holds the result of REV16, why does it keep going to  `Neon_rev16_error: `? It does not make any sense to me.

Comment: The original `mov x4, x2` should have been correct, and when I change the nonsensical `ldr x4, [x2]` back to `mov x4, x2`, I get the function returning 0 as expected.  Can you show your exact test case that didn't work before?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes. I have already edited the code and pasted the original one before the `ldr x4, [x2]`. For some reason the original code is not returning 0 as expected, it is returning the content on the x2 register

Comment: I ran your code (changing only the `ASM_FUNC` to be able to compile it on Linux) and it returns 0.  Are you sure you're running the same version you're editing (saved your source file, recompiled, re-downloaded to your test machine, etc)?

Comment: @NateEldredge, Yes. I am sure. To be 100% sure, I copied the code from this post, pasted on my environment and just ran it again. I even added a different printf to make sure the code compiled properly. The code still returns 43520

Comment: Oh, hang on.  `LD1   {V0.16B},[x1]` is a 16-byte load, but you only have four bytes of good data at the misnamed `oneHundredSeven`.  So the upper 12 bytes get loaded with garbage, and you'll get 4 of them when the `mov x2, v1.D[0]` moves 8 bytes into `x2`.  That would explain why the compare failed.  As for why the output appeared to match, are you sure your `main` function is as you showed it, with `%lu` in the print, and that `unsigned long` is really 64 bits for your compiler?  If you only print the low 32 bits you won't see the garbage.

Comment: There is a mismatch in that `fff` is of type `long int` whereas it should really be `unsigned long int`, though I would not expect that to actually change anything.

Comment: I didn't see it in my original test because the "garbage" happens to be zeros on my system.

Comment: If you just want to load one word from `oneHundredSeven` into the low 32 bits of `v0` and zero out the rest, I believe you want `ldr s0, [x1]`.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh, I see! You are totally right!  I changed it to `oneHundredSeventy: .word 0b0000000010101010` to make sure there is no garbage (also added the "y" missing).
You were right, I was printing u, not lu. The real result is 2199023299072, which is 100000000000000000000000001010101000000000 instead of the 43520  (1010101000000000) expected. Since I made sure there was no garbage, I fail to realize where this first 1 came from

Oh, about `ldr s0, [x1]`, i tested it and it freezes the application at runtime
Btw, I believe my variable has 8 valid bits (10101010)

Comment: `.word 0b0000000010101010` doesn't change anything.  The high bits of that word were already zero.  The problem is the next three words which are also loaded by `LD1 {V0.16B},[x1]` and which are still not initialized at all.  You would need `.word 170, 0, 0, 0` or something like that.  I did test `ldr s0, [x1]` and it works here, so I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: As a general comment, I feel like your life will get a lot easier if you can find a way to test your code in an environment with a proper debugger, instead of having to guess what happens when it "freezes".  My tests are on a Raspberry Pi running Linux; it's also possible to get ARM64-based cloud VMs.

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge I do agree, and in the same vein, I provided him with instructions on how to use qemu-system-arm for debugging  standalone assembly/C code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991510/execution-freezes-when-i-try-to-allocate-array-in-armv8-assembly)  -  to no avail it seems.